# I am trying to create react app but failed. It show error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Creating a new React app in G:\my-react-projects\dovana.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\M Monayem Hossain\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-12-23T14_13_40_614Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting dovana/ from G:\my-react-projects
Done.

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing this from office laptop most probably you might behind the proxy.
So in order to change the proxy configuration you better check with your network team.

We can manually set the proxy with below command

```
npm config set https-proxy <Proxy name of your company>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing cache and then rerun the setup again

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install create-react-app
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 0):

try to install anything from NPM to confirm this is an issue with your connection. npm install -g create-react-app. If this (or any other package) succeeds, it may be other issue.

Consider as well it could be an issue with npx on your machine. Try installing it using create-react-app directly instead by first installing it globally (like I showed above)

Also try this

npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

and this

npm set timeout=100000

Answer (score 0):

can you set the npm timeout value to a longer time:

Step 1:

Can you create a local file called
.npmrc
In the folder set the value for timeout to be:timeout=100000

or

Run the following:

```
npm set timeout=100000
```

Step 2:

Finally run the following set of commands:

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install create-react-app
npx create-react-app ./
```

Comment: Hopefully this works, if not please attach what the error is after completing the steps.